# What is the best practice for abstract classes with overridable methods which return nothing

Tags: .net, oop

What is the best practice for mustoverride/overridable methods in an abstract class which return *nothing*. The concrete class which inherits this abstract class can decide whether or not it requires the functionality and can override as requires.

Now I understand that this is the function of an interface but there is a lot of plumbing code in the abstract class which would be require to be 'unhidden' to implement this.

**My question is it bad design to have these methods in your project?**

**Example 1** - The Concrete class does require the implementation but is forced to override the method.

*(abstract)*

```
Friend MustOverride Function GetTitle() As String
```

*(Concrete)*

```
Friend Overrides Function GetTitle() As String 
        Return nothing
End Function
```

**Example 2** - The Concrete Class can override the method if required but the abstract class contains a method which returns nothing.

*(abstract)*

```
Friend Overridable Function GetTitle() As String
        Return nothing
End Function
```

*(Concrete)*

```
Friend Overrides Function GetTitle() As String
        Return "Title"
End Function
```

Comment: That really depends - is returning Nothing a reasonable default implementation? Sometimes it will be - other times it won't be. Note that your first version returns nothing in the *concrete* class, when presumably it should actually return "Title".

Comment: Hi Jon, The example was to prove why this implementation 'felt' wrong. In example one, the concrete class doesn't want the to use the title method but is required to override the method. In example two the concrete does!! Our project uses example two because then the concrete class doesn't worry about the method unless it is required, but yet it still feels wrong having a method in the abstract class which returns nothing. Thanks for your response :)

Comment: "Best practice" is fast becoming a meaningless term due to being abused like this. The choice is not a product of following best practices, but of *design*.

Comment: @Richard: You're changing two things though: a) whether the concrete class wants to return a value; b) whether the base class declares the method as abstract or not. To be a useful comparison, you should only change *one* of these.

Comment: @JonSkeet Are either examples of a method returning nothing acceptable design decisions in a pure OO world?

Comment: @Richard: In *some* cases, yes. But not in all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is really up to you to decide how you indicate "I don't know".  But returning Nothing from an abstract base class is a pretty lousy habit.  It is liable to generate NullReferenceException in the client code when either the programmer that derives from your class or the programmer that writes the client code doesn't realize that Nothing is a possible value.  NRE is a *lousy* exception to diagnose, the CLR is not capable of giving any meaningful hint about it.  It cannot possibly name a variable that stores the null for example, it knows *Nothing*.

This gets especially difficult to diagnose because the null got generated at least *two* levels away from where this goes wrong.  The user that is saddled with the crash might have to talk to *three* programmers to get to the bottom of the problem.  And is going to be none-to-pleased to finally get you on the phone.

If you cannot provide a meaningful implementation of a member then *never* hesitate to declare it abstract.  This ensures that it won't be you that talks to the pissed-off user.  Returning String.Empty is an alternative.  Maybe it makes sense for your design, I can't guess at that.

Comment: +1 Thanks for you explanation, well I would if I had 15 reputation :)